# Problem calculating relative time in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following data:

```
 ----
ORIGINAL TIME 2011-09-04 12:04:36
FORMATTED TIME 2011-09-04T12:04:36-0700
RELATIVE TIME: 2517s ago
 ----
ORIGINAL TIME 2011-09-04 11:40:17
FORMATTED TIME 2011-09-04T11:40:17-0700
 RELATIVE TIME: 1058s ago
 ----
ORIGINAL TIME 2011-09-04 08:05:00
FORMATTED TIME 2011-09-04T08:05:00-0700
RELATIVE TIME: 3h ago
----
ORIGINAL TIME 2011-09-04 07:16:00
FORMATTED TIME 2011-09-04T07:16:00-0700
RELATIVE TIME: 4h ago
```

I have some code to calculate the relative time (I am passing in the formatted time):

```
+(NSString*)toShortTimeIntervalString:(NSString*)sDate  
{ 
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:[sDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@"-0000"]];
    [df release];

    NSDate* today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *d = date; //[_twitter_dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:d];
    [today release];

    //TODO: added ABS wrapper
    double res = 0;
    NSString* result;
    if(interval > SECONDS_IN_WEEK)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_WEEK);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fw ago", res];
    }
    else if(interval > SECONDS_IN_DAY)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_DAY);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fd ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_HOUR){
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fh ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_MIN) {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_MIN);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fm ago", res];
    }
    else
    {
        interval = fabs(interval);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fs ago", interval];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why am I getting `2517s ago` when it should really not output that as seconds. It should be `41m ago`

The interval in this case is `-2517.0`

Comment: How do you define `SECONDS_IN_MIN` etc.?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this yourself?

Comment: @omz `#define SECONDS_IN_MIN 60`

Comment: I think you're not showing us something.  Further, if you set a breakpoint and step through it with the debugger you should be able to figure it out in short order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)resultDate options:(NSUInteger)opts` method of `NSCalendar` to get the relative time units between now and your dates, using something like this:

```
NSDate *dateToCompare = pointerToYourDatePulledFromTheStringRep;
NSInteger numberOfUnits;
NSString *unitString;
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                          components:(NSWeekCalendarUnit | 
                                       NSDayCalendarUnit | 
                                      NSHourCalendarUnit | 
                                    NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
                                    NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                           fromDate:dateToCompare 
                             toDate:[NSDate date]
                            options:0];
if ([comps week] > 0) {
   numberOfUnits = [comps week];
   unitString = @"week";
} else if ([comps day] > 0) {
   numberOfUnits = [comps day];
   unitString = @"day";
} else if... // hour, minute, second

result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@%@",
                                    numberOfUnits,
                                    unitString,
                                    (numberOfUnits != 1 ? @"s" : @"")]; 
                                    // last bit deals with plurality
```

This way, the OS functions deal w/ all the hairy date math, and you reap the benefits of exactness and multi-calendar compatibility.

As to your your question (technically) about why your seconds are coming out NOT as minutes, I'd guess that `SECONDS_IN_MIN` is defined incorrectly. But, again, using `NSCalendar` gives you a more robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

BTW-- if `interval` is `-2517.0`, you should be checking for `(interval < -60)`. If all your times are in the past, all your macros should be defined negative and your comparisons should be `<`, not `>`. Not sure how your hour times formatted that way, considering this...

You may want to do `(fabs(interval) > SECONDS_IN_UNIT)` (and define them positive) in all your comparisons if your times can be in the future or the past.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an addition to your other answer, rather than a separate post?

Comment: Yes Ben, if you have additions just update/edit into your original answer.

Comment: Ah. I've been generally splitting it into two if I'm taking it two different directions (a la 'and now for something completely different'). But if the community deems this taboo, I can do just one from here onward.